# Transforming the current date and getting the date 7 days earlier

Tags: python

I need to transform dates to this format:

```
#(Optional) Start date in format YYYY-MM-DD%20HH:NN:SS.
```

To make api call and then get from it date 7 days earlier

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta    

end = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d%%20%H:%M:%S")
start = end - timedelta(days=7)
print("Start: ", start )
print("End: ", end )
```

I tried to do it this way but I get an error

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Comment: You need to subtract the delta from `now` rather than the formatted string.

Comment: Ok i got this thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Peter Wood i fixed this silly mistake

```
end_time = datetime.now()
start_time = end_time - timedelta(days=7)
end = end_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d%%20%H:%M:%S")
start = start_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d%%20%H:%M:%S")
print("Start: ", start )
print("End: ", end )
```

Answer (score 0):

With strftime you are casting end to string, remove that part like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

end = datetime.now()#.strftime("%Y-%m-%d%%20%H:%M:%S")
start = end - timedelta(days=7)
print("Start: ", start)
print("End: ", end)
```

If you want to format your output you can then add .strftime("%Y-%m-%d%%20%H:%M:%S") like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

end = datetime.now()#.strftime("%Y-%m-%d%%20%H:%M:%S")
start = end - timedelta(days=7)
print("Start: ", start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d%%20%H:%M:%S"))
print("End: ", end.strftime("%Y-%m-%d%%20%H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: I think they wanted to format the times.

Comment: Yeah I need to have this in format like this `YYYY-MM-DD%20HH:NN:SS`

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from urllib.parse import quote

end = datetime.now()
start = end - timedelta(days=7)
print("Start: ", quote(start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
# Start:  2022-09-27%2008%3A28%3A11
```